# Lua : How to check if one of the values associated with the specified key of a table is nil, from api

Tags: lua

In lua, it's legal to do this :

```
table={}
bar
if(table[key]==nil) then
foo
```

However, using C API, I couldn't find way to check if there's a nil value on the specified position.

```
lua_getglobal(L,"table");
lua_gettable(L,key);
```

If there's a nil value stored in table[key], lua_gettable would give me the "unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to index a nil value)" message.

Is there any way to check if there's actually something associated with that key, before actually pushing the key to do so ?

Comment: I know this is just example code, but you should avoid giving variables names that clobber the standard libraries (`table`, `string`, `os`, `io`...), especially if they're not local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `lua_gettable` wrong. It should be:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "tableVar");
lua_pushstring(L, key);   //assuming key is a string
lua_gettable(L, -2);
```

The second parameter to `lua_gettable` is the stack index to the table, not the key.

If the key is a string, you can call `lua_getfield` instead:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "tableVar");
lua_getfield(L, -1, key);
```

Comment: Gah.
I guess it's time to sleep. Thanks for reminding how to use it.